# Plusieurs personnes se sont sauvées que j'aurais bien imitées

Tags: constructions

*Ne pleure plus, Marie* de Janine Boissard :

> Déçue, lassée, l'assistance ne se privait pas de bâiller. Plusieurs
> personnes se sont sauvées **que j'aurais bien imitées**.
>
> Et puis votre tour est venu.

Pourquoi est-ce que *que j'aurais bien imitées* est placé à la fin de la phrase ? J'aurais écrit *Plusieurs personnes **que j'aurais bien imitées** se sont sauvées* ou *Plusieurs personnes se sont sauvées, **je les aurais bien imitées***.

Answer (score 2):

Janine Boissard prend une liberté stylistique avec l'ordre habituel des mots.

Les phrases que tu proposes sont bien ce que l'on se serait attendu à trouver.